# Latex Image headers and footers

Tags: image, header, latex, footer

I'm triyng to make a institutional page in LaTex, the page must have a Header and a Footer that my institution gives, and cannot be changed, so I'm triyng to force them whith the next code that i've borrowed from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297240/adding-an-image-to-a-header-in-latex

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,top=4cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=3.8cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\fancyfoot[R]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page footer area.north)-(current page.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below right] 
      at (current page.south west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\n1]{exampleH}};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page.north)-(current page header area.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below right] 
      at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\n1]{ExampleF}};
\end{tikzpicture}}





\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Type your document as usual!
\newpage
\section{Second section}
Type your document as usual!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you placed the footer image below the bottom boarder of the page. You'll see it if you place the node above the lower boarder:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,top=4cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=3.8cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}



\fancyfoot[R]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page footer area.north)-(current page.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,above right] 
      at (current page.south west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\n1]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page.north)-(current page header area.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below right] 
      at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\n1]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}





\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Type your document as usual!
\newpage
\section{Second section}
Type your document as usual!
\end{document}
```

[image]